# How to make one renderUI inside a shiny module dependent on another UI from the same module

Tags: r, module, shiny

I've have tried lots of combinations of this to no avail and am all out of ideas.

I have a data.table, DT, and a shiny app with two selectInputs both based off of the same shiny module.
The first inputSelect should subset my data.table based on the first column and the second takes the remaining subset and subsets DT further based on the values of the second column.

I am finding it impossible to make the choices for the second selectInput to be the values from the second column after the subset where the 1st selectInput == col1.

I have included example code for the app below. The actual app I am making is more complicated than this. Everything works up until the second selectInput. I am having problems making this second renderUI reactive.
Would very much appreciate some tips in the right direction.

```
library(data.table)
library(shiny)

myUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput(ns('myFinalText'))
  )
}

ui <- pageWithSidebar(headerPanel = headerPanel(title = "title"),
  sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
                    myUI('menu1')
                  ,
                    myUI('menu2')
                  ),
    mainPanel = mainPanel(actionButton("debug","INSPECT"))
  )

set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(col1 = LETTERS[rep(1:2, each = 3)] , 
                 col2 = LETTERS[sample(1:4, 6, replace = TRUE)],
                 num = 1:6,
                 key = c("col1", "col2"))


myTextFunc <- function(input, output, session, text) {
  output$myFinalText <- renderUI({

    if(text == "textArg1"){
    selectInput(paste0(text,"Val"),"choose",choices = DT[,col1])
    }else{
    selectInput(paste0(text,"Val"),"choose",choices = DT[col1 == input$textArg1Val,col2])
    }

  })
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(myTextFunc, 'menu1', session = session, 'textArg1')
  callModule(myTextFunc, 'menu2', session = session, 'textArg2')
  observeEvent(input$debug,
               browser()
               )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some reactive data manualy

like

```
myTextFunc <- function(input, output, session, text,data) {
  output$myFinalText <- renderUI({
    if(text == "textArg1"){
      selectInput(paste0(text,"Val"),"choose",choices = DT[,col1])
    }else{
      selectInput(paste0(text,"Val"),"choose",choices = DT[col1 == data(),col2])
    }

  })
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  reactive_choose=reactive({
    input$textArg1Val
  })
  callModule(myTextFunc, 'menu1',  'textArg1')

    callModule(myTextFunc, 'menu2',  'textArg2',reactive_choose)



}
```